# Getting a 400 response when doing app authentication for podio app

Tags: javascript, podio

I'm trying to get an access token using app authentication for my Podio App.

Currently, my code looks like so:

```
    const authUrl = 'https://podio.com/oauth/token';
    const data= "grant_type=app&app_id="+appId+"&app_token="+appToken+"&client_id="+clientId+"&redirect_uri="+uri+"&client_secret="+clientSecret;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("requestResponse").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
    xhttp.open("POST",authUrl, true);
    xhttp.send(data);
```

I keep getting a 400 error, which means the request is bad. But I've tested it using Beeceptor and it works and looks fine.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Do you get any response or other kind of error message that just a 400? Check the request in the Networks tab of your dev tools. Does the request (and parameters) look correct?

Comment: @Phillip No, just 400. There is no responseText from the request.

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out. Adding a line of code...

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

This fixed it perfectly.
Found solution here: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207481648-Cannot-authenticate-by-app-id

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution to your own problem 

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot.  Podio API documentation is quite bad they simply say you need to include the [request body](https://developers.podio.com/authentication/app_auth) but not mention the `Content-type` header needs to be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Thanks for pointing this out...